# Implement SCD Type 2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below table is a target table

| ID | NAME | ADDRESS | Building | Floor | date | Start_date | End_date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Mike | India | ATT | 11 | 20-01-2023 | 20-01-2023 | 21-01-2023 | InActive |
| 1111 | Mike john | US | LG | 8 | 21-01-2023 | 21-01-2023 | 31-12-9999 | Active |

and source table is updated like below.

| ID | NAME | ADDRESS | Building | Floor | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Mike | India | ATT | 11 | 22-01-2023 |

I need target to be updated like below incrementally.

| ID | NAME | ADDRESS | Building | Floor | date | Start_date | End_date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Mike | India | ATT | 11 | 20-01-2023 | 20-01-2023 | 21-01-2023 | InActive |
| 1111 | Mike john | US | LG | 8 | 21-01-2023 | 21-01-2023 | 22-01-2023 | InActive |
| 1111 | Mike | India | ATT | 11 | 22-01-2023 | 22-01-2023 | 31-12-9999 | Active |

here  Again ID 1111 return back to same work place  , so i want this row should be active.
Can anyone please help in this?

Comment: this might be fairly involved using sql. would you consider a solution where you load the target and source tables as pyspark dataframes, perform the update using pyspark dataframes, then write (or upsert) the resulting table to the target?